# Mac OS Catalina webserver error : Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: apache, macos-catalina

I have a problem with my localhost under mac OS **Catalina**; here is my error obtained,
I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVHFPzjp064 for the procedure to properly configure my local server, if you can help me solve this problem, maybe it is a security on new macs.

My error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

I thank you in advance

Comment: To resolve the same problem on Mac Monterey, see here: [https://superuser.com/a/205708/1000698](https://superuser.com/a/205708/1000698)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that the **php module** is disabled in Catalina. You have to enable it in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Follow these steps.

1. Open Terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Enter password when prompted.
2. Find `#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` and uncomment it (delete the leading #)
3. To make Apache use index.php first,

scroll down and find the following

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

change to

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

4. Press `Control + X` then `Y` to save changes. Press `enter` when prompted for filename
5. Restart apache by typing `sudo apachectl restart`

Now your site root should work since php is enabled.

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting this permission problem on phpMyAdmin intallation! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick note to say that the httpd.conf is exactly the same in Big Sur, so the same changes as above need to be applied.